# It is + demonstrative pronoun these

Tags: demonstratives, clefts

what would be the correct usage and difference in meaning in the sentences below:

1. It is these small steps that let us ...

or

2. These are the small steps that let us ...

Comment: They mean the very same thing, but #1 is a little fancier, like you're making a speech.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: The first sentence is extraposed from _These small steps let us ..._  Nothing unusual about it at all (except the missing infinitive verb phrase). The second sentence is just an identification, like _This is just mud; that over there is shit_.

Answer (score 0):

"It is these small steps that let us ..."

The sentence above contains a **dummy pronoun phrase**: "It is" is used to make descriptive statements or other statements.

Another example:
"It is true that advanced mathematics is quite difficult."

"These are the small steps that let us ..."

"These are" is **deictic**. It means you are **pointing out** the small steps previously given in the text. They can come afterwards too.

Another example:

The children loved to eat bananas, oranges and apples. **These are** some of the fruit that are easily available in most grocery stores.

Answer (score -2):

In the first sentence you insist a little on the fact that the reason for being able to do something is the possibility of taking the few small steps in question.
In the second you merely  introduce those steps as being the reason. However, the difference is small and some people might not feel that it exists.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The difference is huge between a dummy pronoun and a deictic pronoun.

Comment: @Lambie There is not in my answer any  underplaying of that difference: I do not discuss the difference from the point of view of the grammatical devices used. The difference I point out remains a reality; you are distributing minus votes arbitrarily.

Comment: "There is not in my answer any underplaying of that difference." There was no overplaying it either.